# Javascript function visual bug

Tags: javascript, css, function

I have a small bug where I have created a pop out menu for navigation for mobile mode and there are two buttons which one calls out the mobile navigation bar and one takes it away, I have set the close button to take the menu to the right `-400px` to come out of the sight of the visitor but there is a scroll bar at the bottom of the page where it takes you to the right side of the page where the navigation bar becomes visible again, can someone help me to hide this navigation bar once the close function has been called. Thanks.

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

function showMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "0";
}

function hideMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "-400px";
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Home | LuxxMob</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/360332bae9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <section class="header">
    <div class="menu-header">
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/HD_FILE (2).png" /></a>
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="news.html">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="players.html">Players</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="main-texts">
      <div class="text-box">
        <h1>Welcome To <em>LuxxMob</em></h1>
        <p>
          An upcoming eSports team, recruiting talented gamers and creative content creators.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="hero-btn">About Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--NEXT SECTION MEET THE OWNER-->

  <section class="meet-me">
    <h1>Meet The Players</h1>

    <div class="player-info">
      <p>
        Meet the competitive players, content creators and the owner of LuxxMob. A rapidly growing team of highly skilled members, providing some of the best content and gameplay available on social media currently.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: why not `display = "none"`?

Comment: Can't see it, this is maybe one of the few cases a picture may be useful

Comment: note: css left, right, top, bottom have no effect if the position is static (default) - perhaps you want to make something position absolute or relative or fixed ... anything but static

Comment: @TrueChow: You should add relevant CSS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display = none` and `display = block` to hide/show your div

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

function showMenu() {
  navLinks.style.display= "block";
}

function hideMenu() {
  navLinks.style.display= "none";
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Home | LuxxMob</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/360332bae9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <section class="header">
    <div class="menu-header">
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/HD_FILE (2).png" /></a>
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="news.html">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="players.html">Players</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="main-texts">
      <div class="text-box">
        <h1>Welcome To <em>LuxxMob</em></h1>
        <p>
          An upcoming eSports team, recruiting talented gamers and creative content creators.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="hero-btn">About Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--NEXT SECTION MEET THE OWNER-->

  <section class="meet-me">
    <h1>Meet The Players</h1>

    <div class="player-info">
      <p>
        Meet the competitive players, content creators and the owner of LuxxMob. A rapidly growing team of highly skilled members, providing some of the best content and gameplay available on social media currently.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks this worked but the smooth animation of it appearing from the right disappeared, do you know how to fix this

Comment: do you want the menu to take over/lay atop content or push content aside/down

Comment: overlay the content

Answer (score 0):

You should set `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body or the navigation parent.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `display` properties to hide/show the menu bar or if you really want that slide-left/right animation you can use `trasnform` and transition properties like this:

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

function showMenu() {
  console.log('Show');
  navLinks.style.transition = "all 0.9s";
  navLinks.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
}

function hideMenu() {
  console.log('Hide');
  navLinks.style.transition = "all 0.9s";
  navLinks.style.transform = "translateX(-400px)";
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Home | LuxxMob</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/360332bae9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <section class="header">
    <div class="menu-header">
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/HD_FILE (2).png" /></a>
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <button class="fas fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></button>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="news.html">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="players.html">Players</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="main-texts">
      <div class="text-box">
        <h1>Welcome To <em>LuxxMob</em></h1>
        <p>
          An upcoming eSports team, recruiting talented gamers and creative content creators.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="hero-btn">About Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--NEXT SECTION MEET THE OWNER-->

  <section class="meet-me">
    <h1>Meet The Players</h1>

    <div class="player-info">
      <p>
        Meet the competitive players, content creators and the owner of LuxxMob. A rapidly growing team of highly skilled members, providing some of the best content and gameplay available on social media currently.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```